# Retrieve data from table a, insert into Table B along with other fields

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I am trying to combine the two Sql Commands so that I can populate the data field with the text from the Select Command See below; I would like the text “Note Goes Here” to be replaced with the data from the selectcommand. However I am not sure how to do it.

```
Dim selectCommand As String = "Select Notes from Note Where NoteKey = " & lngNoteKey

strsql = "Insert into Activity (userName,pVisits,timeDate,data,flag)" _ & " Values('" & GetUserName() _ & "', '" & currentPage & "', '" & DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss") & "', '" & "Note Text Goes Here" & "','" & "2" & "')"
```

I'm new to asp.net and vb and sql so be gentle

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: microsoft sql server? mysql? oracle?

Comment: Microsoft Sql server

Comment: your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Please learn to use parameters. Anyway, you can combine INSERT / SELECT in one query. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx gives a couple of simple examples.

Comment: @ADyson thank you for the link and for pointing out the security issue. I'll certain address this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, any INSERT statement of the form

```
INSERT (a, b, c) 
VALUES ( 'constant', 'constant', X from some table Y where Z)
```

can be replaced with

```
INSERT (a, b, c) 
SELECT 'constant', 'constant', X
FROM Y
WHERE Z
```

So you'd want some SQL similar to this:

```
INSERT Activity (userName, pVisits, timeDate, data, flag)
SELECT @UserName, @PVisits, GETDATE(), Notes, 2
FROM Note
WHERE NoteKey = @NoteKey
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple queries on same command and use parameter to protect from sql injecttion:

```
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=TEst//TEst;Initial Catalog=cMind_ProgramGuide;Persist Security Info=False;")
        Dim strsql As String = "Insert into Activity (userName,pVisits,timeDate,data,flag) Select @userName,@pVisits,@timeDate,Notes,@flag from Note Where NoteKey = @note"
        Dim Command As New SqlCommand(strsql, connection)
        Command.Parameters.Add("@userName", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = GetUserName()
        Command.Parameters.Add("@pVisits", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = currentPage
        Command.Parameters.Add("@timeDate", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss")
        Command.Parameters.Add("@note", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = lngNoteKey
        Command.Parameters.Add("@flag", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 2
        connection.Open()
        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        connection.Close()
```